# Angular deployment with build variant?

Tags: angular, angular6

I just want to ask if there is an option when building or deploying an angular project production with **build variant**?,

for example, I want to build or deploy a project with specific variant like.

`ng build --prod --variant=admin` or
`ng build --prod --variant=client`

so that in `dist` directory it will create a separate production project, since the project is creating a sub folder under the `dist` folder so, I am curious if it also possible to create a multiple production under the `dist` folder.

```
|-dist
   |- projectVariantAdmin
   |- projectVariantClient
```

Comment: You can not inject variables into the build, but you can define multiple projects in `angular.json` and point them to the same source folders. It's up to you to define how each project is different, and they can have different output folders.

Comment: specifically you mean I need to change the `sourceRoot` inside the `angular.json`?

Comment: No, I mean you have two projects that share the same `sourceRoot`. You can then use different `main` entry points when compiling. I do this to build a production version that has a lot of debug modules loaded.